# Spring Integration and Jackson Databind | Caused By: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-integration, jackson-databind

I'm having some trouble on a project using spring.integration 5.2.11.RELEASE and jackson-databind 2.10.5. The compilation is going well but when I am deploying it on a weblogic server I get the following issue:

```
<Warning> <HTTP> <ITEM-S110158> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <1cd9f1d2-6bdb-4850-b373-7f003f588db0-00000008> <1626164762850> <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceActivator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0' while setting bean property 'handler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
    Exception Details:
      Location:
        com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
      Reason:
        Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
      Current Frame:
        bci: @7
        flags: { }
        locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
        stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
      Bytecode:
        0x0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0                    
[...]
    Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
    Exception Details:
      Location:
        com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
      Reason:
        Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
      Current Frame:
        bci: @7
        flags: { }
        locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
        stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
      Bytecode:
        0x0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0                    
    
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:176)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1828)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1265)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1442)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:878)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:705)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:251)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:204)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:189)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1921)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3101)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1843)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:884)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:66)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:274)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:507)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:53)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:202)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:52)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments$2.doItem(ConfiguredDeployments.java:741)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.parallel.BucketInvoker.invoke(BucketInvoker.java:138)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:749)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:702)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:381)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:233)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:219)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:133)
        at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1287)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:333)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:375)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
    Caused By: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
    Exception Details:
      Location:
        com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
      Reason:
        Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
      Current Frame:
        bci: @7
        flags: { }
        locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
        stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
      Bytecode:
        0x0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0                    
    
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper.builder(JsonMapper.java:114)
        at org.springframework.integration.support.json.Jackson2JsonObjectMapper.<init>(Jackson2JsonObjectMapper.java:74)
        at org.springframework.integration.support.json.JsonObjectMapperProvider.newInstance(JsonObjectMapperProvider.java:54)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.configureJsonObjectMapperIfAny(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:322)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:317)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:215)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:219)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.<init>(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:54)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.<init>(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:47)
        at org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean.createMethodInvokingHandler(ServiceActivatorFactoryBean.java:54)
        at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractStandardMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandler(AbstractStandardMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:142)
        at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandlerInternal(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:198)
        at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:186)
        at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:60)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:169)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1828)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1265)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1442)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:878)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:705)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:251)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:204)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:189)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1921)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3101)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1843)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:884)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:66)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:274)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:507)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:53)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:202)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:52)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments$2.doItem(ConfiguredDeployments.java:741)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.parallel.BucketInvoker.invoke(BucketInvoker.java:138)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:749)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:702)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:381)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:233)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:219)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:133)
        at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1287)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:333)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:375)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
```

I have the following dependencies declared in my bom/pom.xml file:

```
<properties>
            [...]
            <spring.integration.version>5.2.11.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
            <jackson.version>2.10.5</jackson.version>
            [...]
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            [...]
            <!-- Jackson -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
                <!-- Here I tried to an exclusion but the issue remained -->
                <!-- exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions> -->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-sftp</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            [...]
</dependencyManagement>
```

Does anybody know why is the root cause of this and how to fix it?

Comment: `Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory'` - probably WebLogic overrides your dependencies somehow to something it defaults...